# Android find ImageView by tag

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I'm simply trying to find ImageView by tag, similar to `findViewById`. I found the `findViewWithTag` function but I get an "cannot resolve method..." error when I try to use it.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailed_view);

//This works fine
TextView name =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

//this doesn't
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewWithTag("myTag");
```

Comment: Can you paste the xml of `R.layout.activity_detailed_view`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Activity` and `View` both have `findViewById()` but `Activity` does not have `findViewWithTag()`.  Try this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activity_detailed_view).findViewWithTag("myTag");
```

For this to work, you need to go into your activity_detailed_view.xml layout and give the first container an id of "@+id/activity_detailed_view".

In other words, use `findViewById` to get the activity's view, then call `findViewWithTag()` on that view.